# $.fn.do() method: Execute other code within a jQuery chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is; without leaving the chain, execute some custom/external code (and continue) within the chain. Otherwise; in a deep chain, I will have to re-query for the DOM element to get back where I've left.

The method below allows to execute custom code inside a jQuery chain synchronously or asynchronously.

```js
//Execute code inside a jQuery chain
$.fn.do = function (callback, async) {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        if (async === true) {
            this.queue(function() {
                callback($(this));
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
        } else {
            callback(this);
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

Simplified Usage Example:

```js
var results = {};
$('#some-elem')
    .css({
        //modify some styles here
    })
    .do(function($elem) {
        //do some calculations.. tests here..
        //save them to results object
    }, false) //synchronous
    .css({
        //re-set the styles back to their initial state
    });
```

This could be a longer chain where you could need to enter the `do()` method multiple times.

So;

- Do you think the approach above is legitimate?
- Would you suggest an alternate? Why?

Comment: I'm not sure about the necessity of `.queue()` here - why are you adding a function to the default `fx` queue (will be queued after animations when there are pending animations) if this version of the method is asynchronous? You can probably get rid of that.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté This can be used for many purposes (an external operation or a related operation set to occur after some animation that may need the gathered data inside the `do()` method) so I'm allowing for both async and immediate execution. (I'm also passing the corresponding jQuery element as an argument.) Does it make sense?

Comment: I guess. Let me see, in your example code, the last `.css()` should wait until `do()` calls `dequeue()`?

Comment: The example above is completely synchronous since `.css()` method is executed immediately and `.do()` is called with `false` param. And essentially, `do(func, true)` (async) is only a shorhand for `queue()` which will execute when it's his turn in the queue. You might say that I'm only extending the `.queue()` method with a sync execution capability.

Comment: If your intent is to extend `queue` then this looks perfectly fine. I may take another look tomorrow but there isn't much code to cut out without losing a lot of readability.

Comment: Maybe I should change the signature to `$.fn.do(callback, addToQueue);` so it's more clear.

Comment: Yes, that will be helpful for future readers, both here and in the real world applications that you may use it. I'd personally add a third optional `whichQueue` parameter which may be useful in future, but depends on your use cases.

Comment: Currently this is called "for" the corresponding element (when async is `true`) such as `this.queue()`. Do you mean I could use that `whichQueue` param? Maybe `target` is better.

Comment: i.e.: `target = typeof(target) === 'undefined' ? this : target;` and then `target.queue(...)`. Do you mean this?

Comment: No, I meant `whichQueue` as the `queueName` parameter for [`$.fn.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), so you'd be able to create your own queues instead of just dumping it all on the default `fx` queue. `=]`

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this plugin could be useful, however I think you can drop the async part since it's not any harder to call `queue` directly.

Also, I am not a huge fan of error swallowing or ignoring invalid calls since it makes the code harder to debug. If there's a call to `do` without providing a callback, you should let the developer be notified.

I also like to allow defining the `this` value for the callback function so that you do not need to use `$.proxy` for that purpose.

Finally I allowed to return a value from the callback to change the target object for the rest of the chain. However I am not so sure about this feature since it could harm code comprehension but I am leaving it there as an idea.

Basically it would be as simple as:

```
!function($) {
    $.fn.do = function (callback, thisArg) {
        if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError("the 'callback' argument must be of type 'function'");
        }

        return callback.call(thisArg || this, this) || this;
    };
}(jQuery);
```

*Note: I've defined the plugin within an IIFE so that it still works if `$.noConflict()` was used.*

Comment: +1 for `thisArg`. Though, I wouldn't modify the returned object since this is for keeping the chain. Sure you can call `queue()' easily; `async` acts like a shortcut there. Thanks.